# Quasar change suffix of email depending on option group

Tags: vue.js, quasar, quasar-framework

I'm trying to make a suffix change in an email input when I change an option.
Here is different parts of my code:

```
<q-field
  icon="work"
  label="Institution"
  :label-width="3"
>
  <q-option-group
    type="radio"
    v-model="institution"
    @change="changeInstitution"
    :options="[
      {label: 'Institution 1', value: 'I1', suffix: '@institution1.fr'},
      {label: 'Institution 2', value: 'I2', suffix: '@institution2.fr'}
    ]"
  />
</q-field>
<q-field
  icon="email"
  label="Adresse courriel"
  :label-width="3"
>
  <q-input v-model="email" type="email" suffix="" />
</q-field>
```

I also have these lines:

```
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    changeInstitution () {
      console.log('Change institution')
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      institution: '',
      email: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that when I change the "Institution" choice, I don't have the expected log ("Change institution"). Instead, I have this:

```
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "value"

found in

---> <QInput>
       <QField>
         <QTabPane>
           <QTabs>
             <QModal>
               <QDialog>
                 <Testlogin> at src/components/views/testlogin.vue
                   <QToolbar>
                     <QLayoutHeader>
                       <QLayout>
                         <LayoutDefault> at src/layouts/default.vue
                           <Root>
```

Can anyone give me a hint? I looked at the documentation (http://quasar-framework.org/components/option-group.html#Installation), up to no avail...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using v-model. This is equivalent to

`:value="model" @input="(newVal) => model = newVal"`

So, as a result, @change does not gets called, since @input is emitted first, changes the model, then Quasar components get to compare the emitting value to the model... but since v-model's @input changed model, now the emitting value is same, so Quasar components skip the @change event.

Either use:

1. v-model along with @input
2. The "lazy" equivalent of v-model (`:value="model" @change="(newVal) => { model = newVal; callSomething...() }"`)